# Customized font issue in react-native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

[image]

[image]

Picture 1 is my code but my console spits out this error message.
Please give me any clue how to solve this problem.

expo version is 6.14.4

Comment: Are you using this font family in the root file before preloading?

Comment: yes that is exactly right

Comment: Yeah, load this Font before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems like you are using fonts before loading in an application, `Load these fonts before it uses` ,You can load these fonts while initializing your app or you can extend your loading state to make sure that your fonts are loaded in the app.

Answer (score 0):

there is a version compatibility issue so, install expo-font by expo cli .

```
expo install expo-font
```